# Parsing multi-part emails from maildir

Tags: go

I need to parse a multi-part email files read from unix maildir.
Can you please suggest an appropriate library(s) to do this?

The emails are sucked in via IMAP and dumped to a maildir.
I need to parse those email files and extract all the parts including header, base64 attachments, html parts and plaintext parts.

Thanks

**EDIT**

I know I can search for the libraries with keywords and stuff but I also would like some opinions on quality and experience if possible.

I can deal with the actual maildir and picking up mail files. My concern is the parsing of the multipart emails (being fed as strings) and extracting individual parts.

Comment: https://godoc.org/?q=maildir

Comment: All those libraries deal specifically with the maildir - not with multipart email parsing. Thank you for your help though...

Comment: I haven't used these libraries myself, but probably net/mail, mime, mime/multipart packages from the standard library provide enough functionality.

Answer (score 5):

I've had some luck doing this with the [github.com/jhillyerd/enmime](https://github.com/jhillyerd/enmime) package. Given an `io.Reader` `r`:

```
// Parse message body
env, _ := enmime.ReadEnvelope(r)
// Headers can be retrieved via Envelope.GetHeader(name).
fmt.Printf("From: %v\n", env.GetHeader("From"))
// Address-type headers can be parsed into a list of decoded mail.Address structs.
alist, _ := env.AddressList("To")
for _, addr := range alist {
  fmt.Printf("To: %s <%s>\n", addr.Name, addr.Address)
}
fmt.Printf("Subject: %v\n", env.GetHeader("Subject"))

// The plain text body is available as mime.Text.
fmt.Printf("Text Body: %v chars\n", len(env.Text))

// The HTML body is stored in mime.HTML.
fmt.Printf("HTML Body: %v chars\n", len(env.HTML))

// mime.Inlines is a slice of inlined attacments.
fmt.Printf("Inlines: %v\n", len(env.Inlines))

// mime.Attachments contains the non-inline attachments.
fmt.Printf("Attachments: %v\n", len(env.Attachments))
```

Comment: This library doesn't work if there is any very large single line in the email body.

Comment: Looks like there's a workaround at the moment (with the downside that it changes the original content by chopping up the long string with newlines): https://github.com/jhillyerd/enmime/issues/185#issuecomment-801185131

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example: The part missing is extracting the attachments. Please let me know if you figured that part out... Been scratching my head to extract attachments for weeks now...

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/mail"
)

func extractEmail(mail *mail.Message){
    header := mail.Header

    fmt.Println(header.Get("Date"))
    fmt.Println(header.Get("From"))
    fmt.Println(header.Get("To"))
    fmt.Println(header.Get("cc"))
    fmt.Println(header.Get("bcc"))
    fmt.Println(header.Get("Subject"))

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(mail.Body)
    if err != nil {
        checkErr(err, "Reading Body")
    }

    fmt.Println(body)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in standard library:
https://pkg.go.dev/mime/multipart@go1.16.6#example-NewReader